# Calling a function inside .then() is throwing an error

Tags: firebase, react-native, promise, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to perform some task with firebase and calling some functions inside promise without any callback function and this is giving me an error.
Here is my code

```
onButtonPress = () => {
  const {email, password} = this.state
  this.setState({error: '', loading: true});

  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(this.onAuthSuccess().bind(this))
  .catch(()=>{
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(this.onAuthSuccess().bind(this))
    .catch(this.onAuthFailed().bind(this))
  })
}

  onAuthSuccess() {
    this.setState({
      email: '',
      password: '',
      error: '',
      loading: false
    })
  }

  onAuthFailed() {
    this.setState({
      error: "Authentication Failed",
      loading: false
    })
  }
```

Here is the error message that I'm getting

> undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.onAuthSuccess().bind()')

Comment: You want `this.onAuthSuccess.bind(this)`, not `this.onAuthSuccess().bind(this)` (same for `onAuthFailed`). `bind` is a method of functions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 ways of dealing with `this` context in ES6.

> 1. Use the `bind` keyword

```
onAuthSuccess() {
    ...
}

firebase.auth()
    .then(this.onAuthSuccess.bind(this));
    .catch(this.onAuthFailed.bind(this));
}
```

> 2. Use arrow function to avoid prebinding

```
onAuthSuccess = () => {
    ...
}

firebase.auth()
    .then(this.onAuthSuccess);
    .catch(this.onAuthFailed);
}
```

> 3. Bind your methods in the constructor

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onAuthSuccess = this.onAuthSuccess.bind(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% as the good ol `this` context is confusing!

so I think you want to get rid of the `bind()` and instead use `=>` on your functions. Using the fat arrows will reset the context of `this` so `this.setState` should be right in the context of your class based component.

Here is an example of what I mean

```
onAuthSuccess = () => {
  this.setState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
    error: "",
    loading: false
  });
};

onAuthFailed = () => {
  this.setState({
    error: "Authentication Failed",
    loading: false
  });
};

onButtonPress = () => {
  const { email, password } = this.state;
  this.setState({ error: "", loading: true });

   firebase
  .auth()
  .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(() => this.onAuthSuccess())
  .catch(() => {
    firebase
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(() => this.onAuthSuccess())
      .catch(() => this.onAuthFailed());
  });
};
```

Comment: Calling the functions instead of passing them is still wrong

Comment: I just doubled checked.. are you sure your firebase function is correct?

I have updated my answer with what I believe is the right what to handle the `.then()`